# Untag Docker Image Without Deleting it?

Tags: image, docker, docker-image

I have to untag a Docker image without removing or deleting the image from the host.

Let's say I have an image:

```shell
fedora 28  c3f540d72dfd        2 weeks ago         254MB
```

How I can remove this tag and keep the image as it is on host? I know it would be dangling image, but that's fine for me.

I tried the following command, but it is deleting the image as well:

```shell
docker rmi fedora:28
```

Comment: Why is it important to keep the tag?  Having untagged it, why is it important to keep the image?

Comment: @DavidMaze David, I want this in special case where I tag images and untag after some time but during untagging I don't want to remove/delete the image. Just wanted to untag it. Any idea?

Comment: Judging by this github issue, I'm guessing this is not possible (in any straight forward way) https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/68

Comment: The `docker rmi` command has a `--no-prune` option now, but it does **not** seem to do what it says.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the `docker rmi fedora:28` will remove the tag only if the original image has multiple tags.

If the image has only one unique tag and you try to do `docker rmi` to it.
It will remove the image it self.

The best way is to check the image has multiple tags and then only remove the desired tag.

Comment: For me at the moment the goal is to keep the content around so that if the following steps in the script would fetch the same image, it does not have to do that, and the images that will not get used will be pruned at the end of that. So the image may not have another tag.